# What causes my Java algorithm slower and slower after I start it for the first time?

Tags: java, performance

I made a Java algorithm. It access the MongoDB database. It looks like they don't provide a method like .close() or .dispose(). SO I never use this kind of methods in the codes. Every time I run/debug the program, it becomes slower and slower. Is that any reasons or possibilities, generally or specifically?

Comment: Are you putting lots of stuff in the database and not clearing it out?

Comment: I'm sorry I dont understand. What do you mean "clearing it out"?

Comment: Well, if your program inserts into the database, but doesn't delete the same amount, then your database will slowly increase in size every time you run the program. Bigger database = slower queries.

Comment: You're obviously wearing out the bits.  You need to lubricate them somehow.

Comment: The data is the book tagging data of about 5000 users. But I only access 16 users of them. I only retrieve. I don't insert new data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific problem is that you are probably not cleaning test data out of the database after each run.

But this is also telling you something important about your application's scalability; i.e. that it is likely to slow down noticeably in production as you add more and more data ... in some particular dimension.   You should probably track down what is causing this problem now, rather than waiting until you run into operational problems.

The slow down that you are observing could potentially be a number of things, but I'd start by looking at whether your query performance could be improved by adding appropriate indexes.

---

> I only retrieve. I don't insert new data.

That's what you say.  In practice, *something* must be inserting data ... or something like that.  It is hard to see what else could be causing the slowdown.